# Trying to use a function that returns three values as the input for a function that takes 3 values

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a function that does a few things, but ultimately returns three lists.
I have another function, a set method in a class, which takes three inputs. 
When I try to use the first function as the argument for the set function, it complains that there's not enough inputs, despite the fact its returning the right amount. Is there a way around this? Should I just declare some temporary local variables to do this?

a simplified version of my code

```
class hello(object):
    a, b, c = 0, 0, 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def setThings(one, two, three):
        self.a = one
        self.b = two
        self.c = three

def someStuff(x, y, z):
    newX = x * 1337
    newY = y * 420
    newZ = z * 69
    return newX, newY, newZ

first = int(input("first"))
second = int(input("second"))
third = int(input("third"))
kenzi = hello(input("name pls"))
kenzi.setThings(someStuff(first, second, third))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a asterix before the function when calling it as a argument.

`kenzi.setThings(*someStuff(first, second, third))`

Comment: This was a lot simpler than I had anticipated. Too bad google doesn't pull this up at all. Thanks!

Comment: Docs link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists